# Changing Bokeh Slider callback_policy from throttle to mouseup not working

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

I would like to move freely between 2 callback policies of the slider, "mouseup" and "throttle".

It turns that I can change from "mouseup" to "throttle", but when the callback policy is "throttle" it seems the overwrite of the callback_policy attribute does nothing and the slider remains in "throttle" mode.

Am I overlooking something here?

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application

# this is the real callback that we want to happen on slider mouseup

def modify_doc(doc):
    def cb(attr, old, new):
        print("UPDATE", source.data['value'])

    # This data source is just used to communicate / trigger the real callback
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(value=[]))
    source.on_change('data', cb)

    # add a slider with a CustomJS callback and a mouseup policy to update the source
    slider = Slider(start=1, end=10, value=1, step=0.1, callback_policy='mouseup')
    slider.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        source.data = { value: [cb_obj.value] }
    """)

    def changeMode(attr, old, new):
        if modeSelect.active==0:
            slider.callback_policy='throttle'
            print('settings adjusted to throttle')
            print(slider.callback)
            print(slider.callback_policy)
            print(slider.callback_throttle)
        else:
            slider.callback_policy='mouseup'
            print('settings adjusted to mouseup')
            print(slider.callback)
            print(slider.callback_policy)
            print(slider.callback_throttle)


    modeSelect = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["continuous", "on release"], active=1,button_type='success')
    modeSelect.on_change('active', changeMode)


    doc.add_root(column(modeSelect,slider))




handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)



show(app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below setting the callback_policy on the slider element works but only one direction: from "mouseup" to "throttle". Setting it back to "mouseup" does not have any effect. Maybe this is a bug in Bokeh v1.0.4 or maybe some more attributes in the BokehJS model should be manipulated.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(value = []))

def cb(attr, old, new): 
    print("UPDATE", source.data['value'])

source.on_change('data', cb)

mode_select_callback = CustomJS(code = """
    var slider = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('my_slider')
    if (cb_obj.active == 1)
        slider.callback_policy = "mouseup"
    else (cb_obj.active == 0)
        slider.callback_policy = "throttle" """)

modeSelect = RadioButtonGroup(labels = ["continuous", "on release"], active = 1, button_type = 'default', width = 300)
modeSelect.callback = mode_select_callback
slider = Slider(start = 1, end = 10, value = 1, step = 0.1, callback_policy = 'mouseup', width = 200, name = 'my_slider')
slider.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source), code = "source.data = { value: [cb_obj.value] }")

curdoc().add_root(column(modeSelect, slider))
```

In this case the easiest work-around would be to dynamically create and remove the slider with a different callback_policy. See simplified example below (Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

layout = column()

def create_slider(callback_policy):
    slider = Slider(start = 1, end = 10, value = 1, step = 0.1, callback_policy = callback_policy, width = 200)
    slider.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source), code = "source.data = { value: [cb_obj.value] }")
    return slider

def cb(attr, old, new): print("UPDATE", source.data['value'])

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(value = []))
source.on_change('data', cb)
slider = create_slider(callback_policy = 'mouseup')

def changeMode(attr, old, new):
    global slider
    if modeSelect.active == 0:
        layout.children.remove(slider)
        slider = create_slider(callback_policy = 'throttle')
        layout.children.append(slider)
    else:
        layout.children.remove(slider)
        slider = create_slider(callback_policy = 'mouseup')
        layout.children.append(slider)

modeSelect = RadioButtonGroup(labels = ["continuous", "on release"], active = 1, button_type = 'default', width = 300)
modeSelect.on_change('active', changeMode)

layout.children.append(modeSelect)
layout.children.append(slider)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Both examples should be run with `bokeh serve --show app.py`

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, I will raise an issue on Github. I like your workaround and I will use that in the meantime. Thanks!